# jQuery Select by Name and ID

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a table like so:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Sample1" id="Sample1" value="1" />
                <input type="radio" name="Sample1" id="Sample2" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Sample2" id="Sample1" value="1" />
                <input type="radio" name="Sample2" id="Sample2" value="1" />
            </td>
            etc....
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to be able to select a specific radio button by `name` and `id`. E.G., select the radio button with the name `Sample2` and id `Sample1`. I tried doing this:

```
    $('[id="Sample1"][name="Sample2"]').checked = true;
```

But no luck... How should I be doing this?

Comment: You can only have one id per element on a page

Comment: Indeed. IDs are _unique identifiers_ for elements. What on earth are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: In addition, you cannot define the same ID twice.

Comment: @Richard: That's what we said.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, i know, was just too slow on typing :)

Comment: I agree on all of the above written

Comment: Yeah... I'm not really in control of that. My Boss gave me a URL to a page that generates tables in that format... so thats what I have to work with.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Quit. The input is **invalid**.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins you need to tell your boss then that his inputs are invalid and he needs to change them you can't just ignore the rules of code without consequence

Comment: @Muleskinner - technically speaking "You can only have one id per element on a page" is incorrect - This specification doesn't preclude an element having multiple IDs i.e.   https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute  However, I do believe that what you wished to convey is that an ID MUST be unique within the context of the elements home subtree which IS correct. i.e. that would be "document" for most intents herein.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 $('#Sample1[name="Sample2"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

but elements can only have one id so maybe you want class instead of id

```
  $('.Sample1[name="Sample2"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

then your html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Sample1" class="Sample" value="1" />
            <input type="radio" name="Sample1" class="Sample" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Sample2" class="Sample1" value="1" />
            <input type="radio" name="Sample2" class="Sample2" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

made some changes here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/yRVvJ/)

Comment: This works perfectly, although with the `ID`'s it only ever selects the first radio button (which is expected). I'll have to talk to the boss about switching to `class`...

Comment: @theadamgaskins please see my note above about the id's its really not optional you simply can't have elements with the same id or you will have bad behavior

Comment: "elements can only have one id" is technically speaking incorrect however, it MUST be unique in the elements subtree.

Comment: Oh, you are splitting hairs here, @MarkSchultheiss I think people understand what is meant. However if you would like to edit my post be my guest.

Comment: No worries, that actually kind of goes away with more recent HTML specs also.  Comment really was on my part intended for others as I see a lot of "broken" html with duplicate id's etc (not by you!)  i actually upvoted

Answer (score 3):

`.checked = true` is wrong. Use `.attr('checked', true)`.

Also, you may only use an ID once. IDs are *unique identifiers* for elements. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here, but:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="radio" name="Sample1" id="SampleA" />
        <input type="radio" name="Sample1" id="SampleB" />
        <input type="radio" name="Sample2" id="SampleC" />
        <input type="radio" name="Sample2" id="SampleD" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#SampleC[name="Sample2"]').attr('checked', true);

            // [id="SampleC"][name="Sample2"] works too
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

does [the job](http://jsfiddle.net/JsLWr/).

**Edit**

Actually `.attr('checked', 'checked')` is more portable.

Comment: Yeah... I'm not really in control of that. My Boss gave me a URL to a page that generates tables in this format... so thats what I have to work with.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Quit. The input is **invalid** and anything may happen.